# Office 365 Calendar embed link gives Bad Request error

Tags: office365, calendar

I have an office 365 calendar in an iframe. It was working fine up until a few days ago. It is publicly viewable.

I get the link to share the calendar like so:

[image: screenshot of office 365 calendar settings page]

However when I navigate to the embed URL it just gives me a HTTP Error 400 with the content body just saying *Bad Request*.

Are there any other settings elsewhere that must be configured to get this working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suddenly started working again today. I guess it was a bug at the Office365 backend.